# Can I install Android 4.2.1 AOKP IceColdJelly ROM on my HTC One X by AT&T?

Tags: custom-roms, htc-one-x, att

Can the *Android 4.2.1 AOKP IceColdJelly ROM* that seems to be released for the *HTC One X* international model be installed on *HTC One X* subscribed by AT&T?

I found the update for *HTC One X* on following link :

[Android 4.2.1 AOKP IceColdJelly ROM for HTC One X](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/articles/419230/20121230/htc-onex-android421-jellybean-update-aokp-icecoldjelly.htm)

Does my HTC One X from AT&T support this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't flash an international ROM on your device.
Because your phone's configuration is different than international version.
Details are given below:

**Chipset:** *Qualcomm MSM8960 Snapdragon* (**AT&T**)-----  *Nvidia Tegra 3* (**International**)
**CPU:**    *Dual-core 1.5 GHz Krait* (**AT&T**)-----   *Quad-core 1.5 GHz* (**International**)
**GPU:**    *Adreno 225* (**AT&T**)---------               *ULP GeForce* (**International**)

if you flash this , it may brick your phone.

[See this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1960069)

Comment: Thanks mate, since I am using an unlocked HTC One X from att, if att provides an update for this phone, does my phone able to get it ? It was bought in US and I am using it here at Nepal and its unlocked.

Comment: That means you are not in AT&T network now. Right?

Comment: yeah, im using other network subscriber. He don't have AT&T here at Nepal

Comment: Thanks, I heard Odin is just for Samsung mobiles, isn't it so ? AT&T ROM is not important for me, I would like to install android 4.2.1 with or without HTC Sense.

Comment: If you need 4.2.1 then go for CynogenMod 10.1 Nightly...

Comment: Yeah, I can see CynogenMod 10.1 on this link http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2064621 which has few issues, if I install this, will it be a clean anroid Jelly Beans or it will include HTC Sense too ?

Comment: Its pure android vanilla experience, not HTC Sense..

Comment: can I install HTC Sense separately later ?

Comment: @hsuk Odin is definitely just for Samsungs.